# how to run fortran subroutines using the editor

Tags: fortran

I'm not familiar with fotran but for some specific computation, I need to run a subroutine. I installed Force 2.0 editor. The program I need to run includes several sub-routines. The below is the related subroutine I need to run:

```
SUBROUTINE DEHANTTIDEINEL(XSTA,YR,MONTH,DAY,FHR,XSUN,XMON,DXTIDE)
```

How can I run the codes within DEHANTTIDEINEL subroutine while entering the input variables using Force editor?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that there is a Fortran kernel for Jupyter that does just that :-) It is not for the Force editor but it is the only similar thing for Fortran I know of. https://github.com/ZedThree/jupyter-fortran-kernel/

Comment: @PierredeBuyl: well, well, well, I live and learn.  So, now I wonder if it is *like a dog's walking on his hind legs. It is not done well; but you are surprised to find it done at all.*  I'll maybe have closer look at it.

Comment: The kernel I linked to might not be what I was thinking of. Fernando Perez showed cross-language passing of variables in a presentation -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s98IGzlptHw that was more powerful than the kernel there.